# How can I make vertical-lr traditional Mongolian texts dispaly correctly on iOS broswers?

Tags: html, css, ios, web, mongolian-vertical-script

With the `writing-mode` set to be `vertical-lr`, a text box containing traditional Mongolian doesn't display correctly on iOS as shown in the first part of the first figure below. If the `writing-mode` is `horizontal-tb`, the text displays just fine. How can I make the Mongolian text in the `vertical-lr` mode display correctly on iOS/iPadOS? The vertical and horizontal modes work fine for desktop browsers, though. The html that can reproduce the figures is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @font-face {
      font-family:'hawang';
      src: url('A Traditional Mongolian Font File; Removed because of data sensitivity');
    }
    .mongol-text-vertical {
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
      font-family: "hawang";
    }
    .mongol-text-horizontal {
      writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
      font-family: "hawang";
    }
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Vertical mode; wrong display</h2>
<div class="mongol-text-vertical">
<p>
ᠠᠷᠪᠠᠨ ᠬᠤᠶᠠᠷ ᠵᠢᠯ <br>
ᠮᠤᠡᠭᠭᠤᠯ ᠠᠷᠠᠳ ᠤᠨ ᠲᠠᠭᠤᠤ  
</p>
</div>
<h2>Horizontal mode; wrong display</h2>
<div class="mongol-text-horizontal">
<p>
ᠠᠷᠪᠠᠨ ᠬᠤᠶᠠᠷ ᠵᠢᠯ <br>
ᠮᠤᠡᠭᠭᠤᠯ ᠠᠷᠠᠳ ᠤᠨ ᠲᠠᠭᠤᠤ  
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The webpage in Firefox on iPadOS.
[image: Firefox on iPadOS]

Edit: added the page in a desktop browser.

The webpage in Firefox on Windows 11.
[image: Firefox on Windows]

Comment: share your code so everyone can help you here

Comment: @Crystal Hi Crystal, I added the code and some pictures.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I had to set `text-orientation` as `sideways` so as to make the Mongolian script show correctly in browsers on iOS/iPadOS. I suspect the problem is that browsers on iOS don't support vertical scripts so the default value of `text-orientation` (`mixed`) just doesn't work since the browsers don't know how to *Lays out the characters of vertical scripts naturally* (quoted from MDN).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation

> The text-orientation property is specified as a single keyword from
> the list below.
>
> Values
>
> `mixed`
>
> Rotates the characters of horizontal scripts 90°
> clockwise. Lays out the characters of vertical scripts naturally.
> Default value.
>
> `sideways`
>
> Causes characters to be laid out as they would be
> horizontally, but with the whole line rotated 90° clockwise.

Comment: cool I'm glad you figured it out. :)

Comment: Thank your brain on figuring it out. not me Happy coding :).